# How can I use asp helper inside javascript script?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kentico

I am rendering page layout inside javascript but I would like to use there some CMS helpers. Rendering works well but helpers doesn't work (I obtained "NaN" instead of text I wanted). How can I add helpers to javascript variable?

```
var detailsTemplate =
                    '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">' +
                         '<tr>' +
                               '<th class="info">' +
                                <%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("ReceiptsList.ProductName") %> +
                                '</th>' +
                         '</tr>' +
                            '<tbody>' +
                                '{0}' +
                            '</tbody>' + 
                    '</table>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, I just add:

```
<span runat="server"> <js code..> </span>
```

and changed helper to (without single quotes):

```
<%= CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("ReceiptsList.ProductName") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set single quotation marks around the ASP tags:

```
'<th class="info">' +
  '<%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("ReceiptsList.ProductName") %>' +
'</th>'
```

Look at the code generated and you will see, without the quotes you will have something like `'<th>' + foo + '</th>'` which will cause your current error. With the quotation marks you will have `'<th>' + 'foo' + '</th>'` which will run fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried this '<%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("ReceiptsList.ProductName") %>', "<%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("ReceiptsList.ProductName") %>" and <%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("ReceiptsList.ProductName") %>.  When I use single quotation mark I get "NaN". Maybe the problem is cennected with fact that this code will be put inside repeater?